# error TS2742: The inferred type of 'username' cannot be named without a reference to '.../node_modules/@angular/forms/forms'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting this error in my application:

`forgot-password.component.ts(44,7): error TS2742: The inferred type of 'username' cannot be named without a reference to '.../node_modules/@angular/forms/forms'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.`

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { User } from '../../models';
import { ValidateUsername } from '../../validators/userid-validator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forgot-password',
  templateUrl: './forgot-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forgot-password.component.scss']
})
export class ForgotPasswordComponent {
  forgotPasswordForm: FormGroup;
  @Output() resetPassword: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() onSubmit: EventEmitter<User> = new EventEmitter<User>();
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {
    this.forgotPasswordForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', [Validators.required, ValidateUsername]]
    });
  }
  get username() { return this.forgotPasswordForm.get('username'); }
  passwordToken(event$) {
    this.onSubmit.emit(event$.value);
  }
}
```

The error occurs at this line:

```
 get username() { return this.forgotPasswordForm.get('username'); }
```

Comment: There is a [TypeScript issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36866) that can cause this error after using `npm link`

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42873

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Should try to have callback type, just like this

```
 get username(): AbstractControl { 
   return this.forgotPasswordForm.get('username'); 
 }
```

Comment: i dont think return type `any` should be encouraged. should use `string`

Answer (score 10):

remove

```
"declaration": true,
```

in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Interesting, that works. Curious what the reason is, though. What if you want to build declaration files?

Comment: I'm the one looking for building the declaration files as well, what is the solution then?

Comment: The error with "declaration": true is due to the type being from a dependency of a dependency, making it inaccessible in the current package. You can probably fix this by installing both the dependency and the dependency's dependency in the parent-most package.

Comment: I had to write `"declaration": false,` but it worked

Comment: I think the reason this works is because portability only matters for libraries. If your project is an app then it doesn't matter if it isn't portable.

Answer (score 7):

You need to be explicit on the return type of the property.

```
get username(): AbstractControl { return this.forgotPasswordForm.get('username'); }
```

`forgotPasswordForm` is a [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) and its [get()](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get) method returns an [AbstractControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl) with the following [subclasses](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#subclasses)

Subclasses

- FormArray
- FormControl
- FormGroup

Answer (score 4):

When it says

> This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.

Sometimes you need to check your `tsconfig.json` and see if is there anything wrong with "baseUrl", "paths" and linked packages too.

But in this case, TS is accusing that you have not typed it since it is in your ts config, so either you can type it as "any", create an interface for it or type as necessarily, in this case, as string.

Comment: An example of it?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I found the following fixes:

### #1 Export the reference as type

```js
// Following is not working:
// export type { ObjectId as _ObjectId } from 'mongodb/node_modules/bson';

import type { ObjectId } from 'mongodb/node_modules/bson';
export type _ObjectId = ObjectId;
```

- I import the reference as `type`.
- I use `_ObjectId` as name, in order to avoid IDE autocompletion with it.

### #2 Fix the return type

This is the **worst** solution!

> Use return type as `any`, like: `function foo(): any`

Answer (score -2):

This happened to me when using filesystem syncer (in place of npm/yarn link).

It got resolved by not copying over the `node_modules` folder from the dependency folder.